# GCP getting error in SQL __google_connectivity_prober

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm seeing an error(severity="INFO") in the GCP Logs Explorer for my MySQL Instance

[Note] [MY-000000] [Server] IAM Group Auth: Access denied /Unable to create user entry in the database for the user __google_connectivity_prober: Error_code=UNKNOWN ErrorMessage=unable to perform sync for IAM user because no IAM Groups exist

What is this user and why is my log exploding with logs about it?
This message pop at a rate of about 6 times per minute

How can I fix this? Do I need to add him as a user to the SQL instance?
I found nothing online about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been having the same problem and was able to get in touch with google support. Here is an excerpt of their response:

> I researched about this error and based on my investigation I found that these are logs generated by our internal systems that monitor the connectivity of all Cloud SQL instances, to ensure that we identify problems with the healthiness of the instance early (if they arise) and we are able to mitigate them at a faster rate.
>
> The Cloud SQL Product Team is already aware of this issue and they are actively working on mitigating it. We are rolling out a fix for this issue which is still in progress and we expect it to be completed in the first quarter of 2024. Additionally, we are trying to get the fix through self-service maintenance [2] so that you can then apply the fix at your convenience. Kindly note that a self-service maintenance would require an instance restart.
>
> Please be aware that there is no action necessary on your part to remedy the issue as this is just an internal log that should not be visible, and they should not harm the Cloud SQL instance. I hope this is not affecting your business and your instance, however please confirm and let me know if otherwise.

**tl;dr:** this is a known bug on google's side of things and hopefully they should have a fix ready soon. In the meantime we just have to ignore those log entries.

Comment: Thank you! I found absolutely nothing online about it so i asked here before going to google support, you just saved me the time to contact them.
Did they say where the instructions for the self-service maintenance are?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The link they gave for self-service maintenance was this:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/self-service-maintenance

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue as of today, December 5th, 2023. However, the issue arises with a service account (which I created myself, and has the appropriate roles to access the instance).

I'm using the service account through the Cloud SQL Proxy authentication, but I have absolutely no way to login to the instance. Every connection attempt is denied, with the same log.

I hope a fix is available soon.

(Unfortunately I must post this as an answer instead of a comment, since I do not have 15 reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like an Authentication issue. IAM can’t identify the user __google_connectivity_prober in your MySQL instance. You may want to check if access is provisioned or if the user even exists in your IAM & Admin. If this is a service account, make sure its provisioned with the proper roles for it to function. Attached is a documentation that can be helpful for your use case.[1][2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authentication

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/add-manage-iam-users#creating-a-database-user

Comment: I know that, the problem is that i don't even know what this user is and what is it's purpose

Answer (score 0):

I managed to "`fix`" the error messages by enabling "`Query insights`" for my SQL instance.

I guess enabling "`Query insights`" creates/grants the user "`__google_connectivity_prober`" fixing the issue.